# Update the value of the variable in the service from multiple components

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a service **DisplaysService** which has a variable `moneys`. When I buy something using the `buy button` on the buy component, I am updating the value of the variable in the service from the component. However, the updated value is not reflected in the sell component even though I am getting the value from the service. The value displayed in the sell component is the original value of the variable in the service **DisplaysService**.

**displays.service.ts**

```typescript
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class DisplaysService {
      moneys = 50000;

      constructor() { }
    }
```

**buy.component.ts**

```typescript
    import { DisplaysService } from './../displays.service';
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-buy',
      templateUrl: './buy.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./buy.component.css']
    })
    export class BuyComponent implements OnInit {
      moneys : number;
      Response = {};
      selectedcurrency : string = "Select Currency"

      constructor(private http : HttpClient, private displaysservice : DisplaysService) { }

      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.http.get('https://api.coinranking.com/v1/public/coins?base=EUR&timePeriod=7d') 
        .subscribe(Response => { 
          console.log(Response)
          this.Response = Response 
        }); 
      }

      ChangeCurrencySymbol (newcurrency : string) { 
        this.selectedcurrency = newcurrency;
      }

      ChangeMoneys (moneysspent : Number) {
        this.moneys = this.displaysservice.moneys - Number(moneysspent);
        this.displaysservice.moneys = this.moneys;
      }
    }
```

**sell.component.ts**

```typescript
    import { DisplaysService } from './../displays.service';
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-sell',
      templateUrl: './sell.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./sell.component.css']
    })
    export class SellComponent implements OnInit {
      moneys : number;
      Response = {};
      selectedcurrency : string = "Select Currency"

      constructor(private http : HttpClient, private displaysservice : DisplaysService) { }

      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.http.get('https://api.coinranking.com/v1/public/coins?base=EUR&timePeriod=7d') 
        .subscribe(Response => { 
          console.log(Response)
          this.Response = Response 
        }); 
      }

      ChangeCurrencySymbol (newcurrency : string) { 
        this.selectedcurrency = newcurrency;
      }

      ChangeMoneys (moneysspent : Number) {
        this.moneys = this.displaysservice.moneys + Number(moneysspent);
        this.displaysservice.moneys = this.moneys;
      }
    }
```

[See link to stackblitz reproduction](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ywv5wr)

Comment: Tried fetching the value in ngOnInit() ??

Answer (score 0):

### The Problem

Angular tries to optimize performance by applying changes to the UI when a change is expected to update the UI.

Consider the below sequence of events

- You assign property `DisplayService: moneys` a value 50,000.00
- You assign property `BuyComponent: moneys` a value `DisplayService: moneys`, now `BuyComponent: moneys` value is `50,000`
- You assign property `SellComponent: moneys` a value `DisplayService: moneys`, now `SellComponent: moneys` value is `50,000`
- Now lets update `SellComponent: moneys` and then update `DisplayService: moneys`
- Now we have a problem, there is no way component `BuyComponent` would have been aware of this change

### Solution

A simple approach would be to set the value of `DisplayService: moneys` as a `BehaviorSubject` and subscribe to this in both Buy and Sell components. This way the value will be synched. See Below code

**displays.service.ts**

```typescript
  private readonly initialMoneys = 50000;
  moneysSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject(this.initialMoneys);
  moneys$ = this.moneysSubject$.asObservable();
  updateDisplay({ amount, type }) {
    if (type === "sell") {
      this.moneysSubject$.next(amount + this.moneys);
    }
    if (type === "buy") {
      this.moneysSubject$.next(-amount + this.moneys);
    }
  }
  get moneys() {
    return this.moneysSubject$.value;
  }
```

**buy.component.ts**

```typescript
export class BuyComponent implements OnInit {
  moneys$ = this.displaysservice.moneys$;
  Response = {};
  selectedcurrency: string = "Select Currency";

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private displaysservice: DisplaysService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http
      .get("https://api.coinranking.com/v1/public/coins?base=EUR&timePeriod=7d")
      .subscribe(Response => {
        console.log(Response);
        this.Response = Response;
      });
  }

  ChangeCurrencySymbol(newcurrency: string) {
    this.selectedcurrency = newcurrency;
  }

  ChangeMoneys(moneysspent: number) {
    this.displaysservice.updateDisplay({ amount: moneysspent, type: "sell" });
  }
}
```

**sell.component.ts**

```typescript
export class SellComponent implements OnInit {
  moneys$ = this.displaysservice.moneys$;
  Response = {};
  selectedcurrency: string = "Select Currency";

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private displaysservice: DisplaysService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http
      .get("https://api.coinranking.com/v1/public/coins?base=EUR&timePeriod=7d")
      .subscribe(Response => {
        console.log(Response);
        this.Response = Response;
      });
  }

  ChangeCurrencySymbol(newcurrency: string) {
    this.selectedcurrency = newcurrency;
  }

  ChangeMoneys(moneysspent: number) {
     this.displaysservice.updateDisplay({amount: moneysspent, type:'buy'});
  }
}
```

[See link to stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-eukpys)